# Add one additional File as Project Artifact

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Im trying to make a maven project which has only one xml file as artifact.
Currently i zip the file with this Configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>create-distribution</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>assembly/master.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

But i would like to have the file itself be the artifact.
Is it possible to tell the assemply plugin to just use a file as artifact?

Comment: The question is why you like to have a file which is stand-alone? Is this a configuration?

Comment: I want to the my Base Data in the Nexus, because when a consultant edits the Base Data its getting checked by Jenkins and if the tests succeed the Base Data of the specific Customer should be available for building a new deploy from all Artifacts in the Artifactory without checking out sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `deploy:deploy-file` goal instead. It allows you to upload arbitrary files.

Comment: During a build this is a bad idea cause deploy-file will cause other issues in particular with releases...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [build-helper-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) and the goal `attach-artifact` which looks like this.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- add configuration for antrun or another plugin here -->
      </plugin>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>some file</file>
                  <type>extension of your file </type>
                  <classifier>optional</classifier>
                </artifact>
                ...
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

But usually I can't recommend that.